# Akka based Web Application Architecture

Tags: scala, architecture, cloud, akka

Where can I find some diagrams/discussions/examples for Web Application based on Scala Akka services?
I'm interested how UI should be integrated etc.
Looking into cloud support variants only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you wanted but here is an example for a Scala web application that uses Lift for the front end and Akka in the back end: http://maciejmatyjas.com/2010/07/scaling-web-apps-with-akka/

Source: https://github.com/matyjas/LSUG-Akka-Lift-Demo

Comment: Thanks, I'm just looking for solution I can 'touch'. It's easy to find good example on Spring or EJB.